# What is the role of social websites (such as Facebook) in Sustainable Living?

Tags: lifestyle

We spend lots of resources and time on social networking websites from all over the world. How we justify social networking sites are brings people, society together? Are there net gain or net loss?

Comment: Hello there, and welcome. I think I can see what you're asking here. Can I just check with you that I've got it right. I think you're asking whether social websites make a net contribution to sustainability: does their contribution to social cohesion, outweigh the cost of the resources used to build and maintain those sites and the infrastructure that goes with them? Is that right? (and I don't know where you live, but maybe there are natural resources there, they just haven't been tapped yet)

Comment: Dear @EnergyNumbers, My question same as your's prediction. Basically I am from Punjab, India & You are right about the natural resources haven't tapped here right now but I wonder about their role & placement in future. Where one thing I feel that this social sites bring us together without any purpose so I confused Is this the better way to come & bring together for some betterment & meaningful towards the society. As I Think this Stackoverflow Q&A sites is good way to come together with some common purpose.! Please correct me if my understanding is wrong about social sites.   Thankyou.

Comment: It only depends on us and the use we make out of them. That's mainly only a tool and, as such, it almost always depends on us, about what we decide to use it for and the way we use it.

Comment: @JeromeJ Thankyou for suggestion & You are right it's depends upon us. But Personally I feel One thing when we have no work to do & in free state then we are gonna more towards social sites(not say as always). But Is this be a fact..?

Answer (score 8):

(If I have understood your question properly)
 The major role of Social Networking sites in the sustainable living is:

1. **Spreading awareness** about the environmental problems that we are facing today.
2. **Educating** others and clearing the doubts of others as well as ours related to the field of environment and sustainable living. (That's what sustainability.SE does).
3. **Discussing sustainability ideas**, methods, tricks, policies of government to exploit natural resources and other legislations including talks at [UNFCCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Framework_Convention_on_Climate_Change) and other platforms, lifestyles etc. This discussions can help to conclude which steps to follow to protect environment, whether the policies and methods to exploit natural resources in the certain areas are right or wrong etc.
4. **Encouraging others to take care of environment** and live responsibly without damaging the environment.
5. **Organizing public opinions, *if needed,*** against any government policy or any industrial plants or undertakings which can have hazardous impact on the environment. ([Arab spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Spring) is a lively example of the role social networking sites can play in mobilizing the public opinion).  This can play strong role as a pressure group and will help to pressurize reluctant political leaders to take beneficial steps to protect environment.

Answer (score 3):

The most important role for social media I see is to **provide the alternative solutions** to those that we are bombarded in mass media and advertisements.

The promoted model of life is `buy-as-much-as-you-can, throw-as-fast-as-you-are-bored.`

We can provide the **tips, how to**:

1) **Save money** by buying more consciously, and therefore less

2) **Repair** things, therefore use them longer

3) **Reuse** the things that are broken (for example use parts of old clothes for cleaning up floor or sealing up the roof)

Comment: Lech Thanks for your proposal. This is to be one of our Desire that These 3R approach can be implemented. But the issue arise how that can be implemented? I Think there is two parts Body & Self(I) in every Human Being But need of each of part are different & Basic Desire of each human is live a life with continuous happiness  Where problem occur when we want to fulfill the need of self like feelings (Respect) on the basis of things like big cars, branded cloths, beautiful house etc.

Answer (score 1):

People certainly still meet others at social venues like clubs and parties, but it is easier than ever to discover people who share our interests through social media, whether that means via groups on Facebook or following people twitter